# How do I configure gvim to open files from the current directory?

Tags: windows, vim, shell

On Windows, no matter what I set as the current directory, gVim will always set its initial working directory to `$home`. (That is, if I launch gVim with the current directory at `C:\something`, or if I set its starting directory to something on my desktop shortcut, vim will not honor this working directory.)

This gets quite annoying when I try to open up a file from the command line by entering something like `gvim file.txt`, since it will always assume it's a new file to be created in the `$home` directory.

Is this something wrong with my vim configuration, or is this default behavior? If it's the default behavior, is there a way to change it?

Comment: I just do gvim .\file.txt if I want to work on a file in the local dir.

Comment: The weird thing about my computer though is that it will only open `C:\Users\Username\file.txt` if I type that in.

Comment: Oh, I may have misunderstood. You are doing this from within gvim? Or at a command prompt?

Comment: Command prompt.

Comment: That's really odd then. What I posted works fine for me.

Comment: Oh wow. I just realized that I put `cd $home` in my vimrc. Closing question.

Answer (score 0):

Check the settings of your GVim, like:

```
Edit -> Global Settings -> Search path
```

Make sure that you have dot as the first argument.
I've:

```
.,/usr/include,,
```

but it depends of your system (you're on Windows, you should have different paths, but you should have this dot at least).

You can also try to run from the command line, so the current working directory should be passed into your gvim.